# How to fix the error generated by magento marketplace technical report

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-community

I have uploaded an extension to the Magento marketplace and during the technical review, an error is reported. The details are the following.

> Errors during installation
>
> Please visit the Magento DevDocs guide in order to learn how to
>   install extensions and use CLI.
>
> Environment: Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 5.6, Magento
>   Platform - 2.1 CE
>
> > Command: composer require mynamespace/myextension:1.0.0' Installation
> >     issue: Do not run Composer as root/super user! See
> >     https://getcomposer.org/root for details ./composer.json has been
> >     updated Loading composer repositories with package information
> >     Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
> >     not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> **Problem 1**
>
> > - Installation request for magento/magento2ce 2.1.4 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2ce[2.1.4].
> > - mynamespace/myextension 1.0.0 requires magento/framework ~100.0.4 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12,
> >       100.0.13, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9].
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.10|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.11|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.12|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.13|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.4|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.5|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.6|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.7|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.8|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - don't install magento/framework 100.0.9|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.4
> > - Installation request for mynamespace/myextension 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mynamespace/myextension[1.0.0].
>
> Installation failed, reverting `./composer.json` to its original
>   content. Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished:
>   FAILURE

My composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "mynamespace/myextension",
  "description": "Decription will come here",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Mynamespace\\Myextension\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: please post here your composer.json file here

Comment: {
  "name": "mynamespace/myextension",
  "description": "Decription will come here",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Mynamespace\\Myextension\\": ""
    }
  }
}

Comment: @KeyurShah Shah , did i miss anything in the composer.json file ?

Comment: I think you should remove this line "magento/framework": "~100.0.4 from composer.josn file @MGento

Comment: I have added answer for you @Mgento :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment I am adding my answer,

In you composer file you have to remove this line

```
magento/framework": "~100.0.4
```

Because It trying to fetch old magento data Instead of new.

Comment: hey @Keyur can you please give thoughts on this **https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/312271/73212** which is similar to this issue