# Magento 2 Marketplace Varnish Test Failed Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: magento2, composer, varnish, testing, marketplace

**I have uploaded the extension on the marketplace but it's failed in varnish test.**

```
Error:- Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.  Problem 1    - Conclusion: don't install composer
```

**Status PASS in the report for the following configurations:**

```
Environment: PHP 7.1.33 Magento 2.3 EE
Environment: PHP 7.1.33 Magento 2.3 CE
Environment: PHP 7.2.30 Magento 2.3 EE
Environment: PHP 7.2.30 Magento 2.3 CE
Environment: PHP 7.3.17 Magento 2.3 EE
Environment: PHP 7.3.17 Magento 2.3 CE
```

**Status FAIL in the report for the following configurations:**

```
Environment: PHP 7.1.33 Magento 2.2 EE
Environment: PHP 7.2.30 Magento 2.2 EE
Environment: PHP 7.0.32 Magento 2.2 EE
```

> Here is the report from marketplace,

```
{
   "tool":"varnish",
   "status":"FAIL",
   "reports":[
      {
         "php_version":"7.1.33",
         "magento_platform":"M2",
         "magento_edition":"EE",
         "magento_version":"2.2",
         "tool":"varnish",
         "myvendor":"myvendor",
         "extension":"module-giftcard",
         "version":"2.0.2",
         "status":"FAIL",
         "date":"2020-05-07 13:45:00",
         "details":[
            {
               "command":"composer require myvendor\/module-giftcard:2.0.2 2>&1",
               "output":".\/composer.json has been updated
               Loading composer repositories with package information
               Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
               Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

                 Problem 1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.6
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.5
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.4
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.0-RC
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.1
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.5 requires composer\/composer ^1.9 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.6
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.5
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.4
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.0-RC
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.5
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.4
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.0
                   - Installation request for myvendor\/module-giftcard 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by myvendor\/module-giftcard[2.0.2].
                   - Installation request for magento\/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.11 -> satisfiable by magento\/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.11].
                   - myvendor\/module-giftcard 2.0.2 requires magento\/module-catalog ^103.0 -> satisfiable by magento\/module-catalog[103.0.4-p1, 103.0.5, 103.0.4-p2, 103.0.0, 103.0.1, 103.0.2, 103.0.3, 103.0.2-p2, 103.0.4, 103.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4-p1 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.5 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4-p2 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.0 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.1 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.2 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.3 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.2-p2 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.3-p1 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.3-p1 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.4 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.2-p2 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.3 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.2 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.1 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.0 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.4-p2 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.4-p1 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.0-RC


                   Installation failed, reverting .\/composer.json to its original content.
               "
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "php_version":"7.2.30",
         "magento_platform":"M2",
         "magento_edition":"EE",
         "magento_version":"2.2",
         "tool":"varnish",
         "myvendor":"myvendor",
         "extension":"module-giftcard",
         "version":"2.0.2",
         "status":"FAIL",
         "date":"2020-05-07 13:45:23",
         "details":[
            {
               "command":"composer require myvendor\/module-giftcard:2.0.2 2>&1",
               "output":".\/composer.json has been updated
               Loading composer repositories with package information
               Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
               Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

                 Problem 1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.6
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.5
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.4
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.10.0-RC
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.1
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.5 requires composer\/composer ^1.9 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.9.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.6
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.5
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.4
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.8.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.0
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.7.0-RC
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.5
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.4
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.3
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.2
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.1
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.0
                   - Installation request for myvendor\/module-giftcard 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by myvendor\/module-giftcard[2.0.2].
                   - Installation request for magento\/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.11 -> satisfiable by magento\/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.11].
                   - myvendor\/module-giftcard 2.0.2 requires magento\/module-catalog ^103.0 -> satisfiable by magento\/module-catalog[103.0.4-p1, 103.0.5, 103.0.4-p2, 103.0.0, 103.0.1, 103.0.2, 103.0.3, 103.0.2-p2, 103.0.4, 103.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4-p1 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.5 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4-p2 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.0 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.1 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.2 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.3 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.2-p2 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.3-p1 requires magento\/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento\/framework[102.0.4-p1, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.0, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.4, 102.0.3-p1].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.3-p1 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.4 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.2-p2 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.3 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.2 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.1 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.0 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.4-p2 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - magento\/framework 102.0.4-p1 requires composer\/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer\/composer[1.10.0, 1.10.0-RC, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-RC, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3].
                   - Conclusion: don't install composer\/composer 1.6.0-RC


                   Installation failed, reverting .\/composer.json to its original content.
               "
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "php_version":"7.0.32",
         "magento_platform":"M2",
         "magento_edition":"EE",
         "magento_version":"2.2",
         "tool":"varnish",
         "myvendor":"myvendor",
         "extension":"module-giftcard",
         "version":"2.0.2",
         "status":"FAIL",
         "date":"2020-05-07 13:45:56",
         "details":[
            {
               "command":"composer require myvendor\/module-giftcard:2.0.2 2>&1",
               "output":".\/composer.json has been updated
               Loading composer repositories with package information
               Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
               Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

                 Problem 1
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.3-p1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.2-p2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.3 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.0 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4-p2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.5 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - magento\/module-catalog 103.0.4-p1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
                   - myvendor\/module-giftcard 2.0.2 requires magento\/module-catalog ^103.0 -> satisfiable by magento\/module-catalog[103.0.4-p1, 103.0.5, 103.0.4-p2, 103.0.0, 103.0.1, 103.0.2, 103.0.3, 103.0.2-p2, 103.0.4, 103.0.3-p1].
                   - Installation request for myvendor\/module-giftcard 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by myvendor\/module-giftcard[2.0.2].


                   Installation failed, reverting .\/composer.json to its original content.
               "
            }
         ]
      },
```

**I think the error is in require section of composer.json file but I'm not sure. I don't understand what could be causing this error.**

> composer.json

```
{
    "name": "myvendor/module-giftcard",
    "description": "Magento 2 Gift Card",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/module-catalog": "^103.0",
        "magento/framework": "^100.1||^101.0||^102.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Myvendor\\GiftCard\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I've tried changing the "require" section, but marketplace is sending the same report as mentioned above.

```
"require": {
        "php": "~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0",
        "magento/module-catalog": "103.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.1.*||101.0.*||102.0.*"
    },
```

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: The key errors are at the end: "your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement". You need at least 7.1.3

Comment: Thanks for your comment but what do you mean I need the php version 7.0? do I need to add the php version in composer.json? Also, this is submitted in the marketplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I changed the require section of the `composer.json` file and it passed in marketplace varnish test,**

```
"php": "~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0"
```

> **composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "myvendor/module-giftcard",
    "description": "Magento 2 Gift Card",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Myvendor\\GiftCard\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worked for me as well. Thanks a lot.