# Installation & Varnish Test Results Failed on magento marketplace

Tags: magento2, composer, marketplace, meqp2

Installation & Varnish Test Results Failed on Magento Marketplace

[image: Magento Marketplace Installation & Varnish Test Results]

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "vendor/preorder",
    "description": "Pre Order",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
       "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.14||~7.3.0||~7.3.1||~7.3.2||~7.3.3||~7.3.4||~7.3.5||~7.3.6||~7.3.7||~7.3.8||~7.3.9||~7.3.10||~7.3.11||~7.3.12||~7.3.13"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "app/code/Vendor/Preorder": ["vendor/preorder"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["registration.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Preorder\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error)**

**require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...**

Comment: There is an issue from Magento marketplace, they are fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

I have solved this by adding a  **auth.json** file  in the root

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<public_key>",
            "password": "<private_key>"
        }
    }
}
```

Refer this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html

Comment: what do you mean in the root? module directory?

Comment: create a auth,json file in root directory

Comment: you mean in the marketplace? do you have a path or steps to follow?

Comment: yes, you have to add auth.json file in root folder for upload a module package in magento  marketplace if you have any doubts

Comment: can you share a link or screenshot ?

Comment: for what?? @Mohit

Comment: for adding the auth.json file. you said auth.json file should be added in marketplace right? so is there any link or screenshot to follow?

Comment: Refer this  document https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html

Comment: thanks. On this path **/home/magento_user/.composer/auth.json** i have to create file?

Comment: no, /home/magento_user/.composer/auth.json this path not working. you just have to put a auth.json in the module root directory

Comment: just to confirm this should be the path **Myvendor/MyModule/auth.json** right? if you could just share your file path that would be easy to understand exactly where should I create the file.I'm confusing between Magento root directory(doesn't make sense) or Module directory

Comment: the path is **myvendor_mymodule-2.0.2/auth.json** used in magento marketplace

Comment: Thanks. It passed in the marketplace.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, it was from their side, but for someone else having the same issue, I recommend to check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/312913/16416) and this [Devdocs page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html?_ga=2.98549407.1472286197.1534791703-1428708218.1532626952#sample-composerjson-file).